# Como evitar a função do método ajaxStop() em uma única chamada ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tenho o seguinte problema:

Há uma página onde utilizo o $.ajaxStop para dar um $.unblockUI (plugin de modal), isso faz fechar o modal "carregando..." sempre que as requisições ajax da página terminam de carregar, o $.ajaxStop serve para isto, um "padrão" para todas as requisições do documento.
Mas tenho uma única chamada ajax onde não quero que o $.unblockUI seja executado... tem algum jeito de fazer isso acontecer somente naquela requisição?

Comment: Você customizou as chamadas ajax na sua aplicação e dentro do ajaxStop você adicionou o código para fechar o modal. É isso? Se for, posta a customização.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar um plugin no jquery mais ou menos assim:

```
$.fn.meuAJAX = function(){
    var url = arguments[0];
    var dados = arguments[1];
    var callback = arguments[2];

    $.post(url,dados,callback);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(this).meuAJAX('/echo/json/',{data:'teste'},function(data){
    console.log(data)
  });
});
```

Você pode enviar um argumento adicional para o meuAJAX indicando true/false para o modal.

Segue exemplo:
[link](https://jsfiddle.net/06tx7k5h/)